# Revenue significance test

Tags: statistics

I would like to ak if is it possible to make a significance test for revenue from A/B testing when I have these data:

```
               | Visits |  Transactions |  Conversion rate |  Revenue  |

Original Page: |  9127  |       96      |      1,05 %      |  161 001  |

       Test A: |  9238  |       88      |      0.95 %      |  129 901  |

       Test B: |  9073  |       98      |      1.08 %      |  175 977  |
```

My question is if I can say from these data that with 90%, 95%, 99% confidence is Test A or Test B significant. Also I would like to know if it´s possible to do it somehow in excel or is there some online calculator? Thanks for any response in advance.

Comment: Still no suggestion guys? I would appreciate any help